# Asynchronous DML operations tracking

Tags: oracle12c

I want log the DML operations on the Oracle table I.e pre and post state objects asynchronously without trigger.can anyone suggest me on this?

Comment: What sort of logging do you want?

Comment: I am performing bulk upsert operations using batch job on Milians of record on couple of tables.I want to capture pre and post state of record as a json object and store it in event log table.I don't want this to be happen along with batch job since it effects the performance? Can u suggest me any way in oracle I can capture this changes asynchronously?

Comment: Is there any way Bob?

Comment: I'm thinking about it :)  One path of research is Auditing. Auditing is quite comprehensive, but there might be pieces of it that will given you what you need. Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/auditing.htm#DBSEG1023

Comment: One more approach would be to use [Continuous Query Notification](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_cqn.htm#ADFNS548) and perform `minus` on same table whenever the conditions are met.

Comment: But I have tried CQN approach its failing in 12c says this feature no longer supported in pluggable database